# How to execute a client-side Git hook?

Tags: github, push, hook, githooks

I am having problem while implementing a **pre-push** hook. The developers need to run a static code analyzer before they push the code to the git repo. But usually they don't and hence break the build.

Thus, I have written a **pre-push** hook; which is a shell script to execute the static code analysis ( and copied to .git/hooks) directory but it is not working correctly. This has to be a **client-side** hook but it is not working as expected. And I dont want to implement this functionality in a pre-commit or post-commit hook since I want static code analysis to be done on the developer's machine before he/she pushes the code (and not when he/she) commits the code.

Thus, please provide your insight as to how I can execute a task (static code analysis) on the client machine before **git push** command.

Comment: Have you copied .git/hooks/pre-push to all the client machines that you want this to be executed?

Comment: Yes. I did the same.

Comment: Are the hooks executable (`chmod a+x .git/hooks/pre-push`)?

Comment: Also, make sure your clients are using Git > [1.8.2 when pre-push was introduced](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt)

Answer (score 1):

As @sestus said, hooks need to be set up client-side, they are not part of the Git repository. It makes sense if you consider that Git is a distributed system and hooks can execute arbitrary code.

What you can do is check in the script into the repository (e.g. to `$REPO_ROOT/git-hooks/pre-push`) and use the build toolchain of your project to set the up a symlink (`ln -s ../../git-hooks/pre-push .git/hooks`).